# No way to get flash working on chromium

Tags: debian, adobe-flash

I’m using the current debian testing.
I have tried these packages :

- `flashplugin-nonfree`, which is currently [bugged](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=851066)
- `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` which doesn’t seem to do anything at all, as nothing appears in the `chrome://plugins/` tab

Any ideas on how to make flash work on chromium ?

All the solutions I found were all either outdated or just telling me to install these packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try our [bunsen-pepperflash package](https://www.bunsenlabs.org/repoidx.html#bunsen-hydrogen-bunsen-pepperflash):

This downloads libpepflashplayer.so directly from Adobe and also installs a systemd .timer unit to check and update the plugin daily.